# C program is not running in Visual Studio Code (version 1.54.3)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am using vscode for running c program. I have installed recommended C/C++ package. I also have installed mingw and also added it to the path successfully.

I already followed the procedure of vscode for C/C++. After pressing `crtl+shift+B` the below message is showing.

```
> Executing task: C/C++: gcc.exe build active file <

Starting build...
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -g "D:\My Codes & Projects\Codes\SPL Assignments\23 March 2021\Solution_01.c" -o "D:\My Codes & Projects\Codes\SPL Assignments\23 March 2021\Solution_01.exe"
Build finished successfully.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

According to vscode user guide there should be a terminal like the below image:
[image]

But I am getting this.
[image]

My whole window screenshot:
[image]

How can I fix the problem? Please help me get the solution.

Comment: It looks like you're only building the program, not executing it.

Comment: The terminal is not showing the directory after pressing crtl+shift+b. That's why I can not executing it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I think OP knows he has been building it, but want to know where he can get a terminal with  a command line interpreter. Since I have been happily avoiding Visual Studio since version 7.0, I cannot help.

Comment: So what can I use for c/c++ sir?

Comment: Clicking the `+` icon will open you a new terminal where you can execute the program

Comment: @anastaciu Thank you so much sir. Life saver.

Comment: Or just 'press any key to close it.' like it tells you. Then you'll be back at your regular terminal.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `Ctrl + Shift + P` to enter commands and search for `View toggle terminal`. You will also see a shortcut to it at the end of the line

Comment: @HAL9000 OPs question is about Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio. There is a huge difference between them. If you want to give VSC a shot, you can even try it in a browser using [Gitpod](https://www.gitpod.io/) for example